# JavaFX 2 - what component use to represent mechanical switch

Tags: user-interface, javafx-2

i would like to design a component that look like a switch that has 3 position.  One neutral position, and upper switch position, when the user click on the upper half of the component and a lower switch position, when the user click the lower half of the component.  When the mouse is released the switch go back to neutral position.  I have got 3 switch images for these position.  I was thinking using a `Button` then check if the mouse click coordinate is in the upper half or the lower half then set images accordingly.  I am looking for any better suggestion, if possible with the use of css for the images (i don't know if it is possible though), or any other suggestion with the use of another component if it is more suitable.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i did, it works...

```
final Button rstButton = new Button();
    final Image rstNeutral = new Image(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("images/switch_neutral.png"));
    final Image rstUp = new Image(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("images/switch_on.png"));
    final Image rstDown = new Image(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("images/switch_off.png"));
    final ImageView rstImage = new ImageView();
    rstImage.setImage(rstNeutral);
    rstButton.setGraphic(rstImage);

    rstButton.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent me) {
            double mouseY = me.getY();
            double buttonY = rstButton.getLayoutY();
            double buttonHeight = rstButton.getHeight();

            if(buttonY + mouseY > buttonY + (buttonHeight / 2)) {
                rstImage.setImage(rstDown);
            } else {
                rstImage.setImage(rstUp);
            }
        }
    });

    rstButton.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent arg0) {
            rstImage.setImage(rstNeutral);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use three component instead of one.

For exemple, you could use three instance of ToogleButton. This component is like a button in appearance, but have a toogle state (clicked/unclicked). I never use it in javaFX but I think you will find enough help on the oracle site (for example : http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/toggle-button.htm)

---

EDIT :

After comment, I think an image of a mechanical switch (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html) could be the solution. If you're showing the switch from the side you can change the rotation of the image according to the state of the switch.

For knowing where the user clicked, locating the position of the button could work.

Another solution could be to had three transparent region on top of the image and intercept the click event on these region, instead of the image. Having never used such a solution, I can really help you more.

Last solution I see could be the use of two another image component on the side of the switch image, showing two arrow, for pulling up or down the switch.

Comment: Hello, i can't use three button, it has to be one as the look must be like a mechanical or electrical switch.